# Best way to repair damage

Tags: repair, damage

I've had kinda of a crash today on my bike. To keep it short, I bumped into a small sidewalk and ended up losing control and crashing into a small wall and went over it (me, not the bike). I was about to get up on the bike when I noticed some damage and eventually decided to go back home (not riding).

As I know 0 about repairing a bike I thought about asking around here to find out what's the best way to fix the damage. Below are some images of a couple of dents in front of the frame and on the wheel.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is the tendency that long-winded answers with lots of pictures get upvoted, but personally I like short and straight to the point

Answer (score 4):

The frame damage is more cosmetic I could tell from the pictures. The quick release can be replaced at low cost. The bigger problem could be to take it out because the end of the thread looks bend and damaged. Best go to your LBS (local bike shop).

Comment: As long as the wheel spins cleanly, and smoothly, and the brakes work properly, then its fine.   Good spotting on the QR thread- they're cheap to buy. I'd try straightening the QR then unthreadding.  If it snaps while straightening then brute force to unthread, or a small cutoff wheel in a dremel will help.

Comment: The other end of the QR should still be able to be undone, and it can be pulled out on the side we are seeing.

Comment: a hacksaw or grinder could also be used, because you're going to throw the whole QR away anyway.